# How to manage amount along with card detail in stripe in android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to perform payment in android app. i am generating card token using this code and it is working giving me token id here is the code..

```
card =  Card.create(
                    cardNumberField.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.valueOf(monthField.getText().toString()),
                    Integer.valueOf(yearField.getText().toString()),
                    cvcField.getText().toString()
            );
```

and this is the output..

```
card -> tok_1FHOLNGvHEQhfjqvHforTUsV
```

Now i am not understanding where i have to send payment amount to get the status that payment is done or not. Please guide. Thank You

Comment: After getting token you have to send to server side there payment initiation will happen

Comment: Look into stripe API. This might help: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create

Comment: @Rameshsambu please elaborate your answer

Comment: You are creating tokens in your app, which is actually an outdated way of doing things. I suggest you discard what you have and follow this guide instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/android